# Binary Semaphores and Buffers to sequentially print

Tags: java

I'm attempting to print a combination of characters.

Character 1 and 2 must be in sequence as follows: 1212121212. Character 3 prints intermittently, but must not exceed Character 2.

I have managed the first part of the task (1 and 2), but struggling with the introduction of 3. I know I need to use a counting semaphore to crack it.

This is for school, so please could you avoid pasting any code and just give me some pointers? I'm just showing two classes: my buffer, and Threads that print the characters.

Thanks.

```
public class PrintLetterA extends Thread {

   private char letter;
   private Buffer buffer;

   public PrintLetterA(char letter, Buffer b) {
      this.letter = letter;
      buffer = b;
   }

   public void run() {

      while (true) {
         if (letter == 'F') {
             Object a = new Object();
             buffer.put(a);
             System.out.println("" + letter);
             try {
                 Thread.sleep( (int) Math.random() * 100);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        } else if (letter == 'G'){
             Object a = buffer.get();
             System.out.println("" + letter);           
             try {
                Thread.sleep( (int) Math.random() * 100);
             }  catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

---

```
public class Buffer {

    private Object message = null;

    BinarySemaphore Fbinary = new BinarySemaphore(1);
    BinarySemaphore Gbinary = new BinarySemaphore(0);


    public synchronized  void put(Object message) {
          try {
               Fbinary.P();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          this.message = message;
          Gbinary.V();
   }

  public synchronized Object get() { 
       try {
         Gbinary.P();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

       Object m = message;
       Fbinary.V();
       return m;
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate *could you avoid pasting any code and just give me some pointers?*

Comment: How can we give you pointers if you are using Java (try using C++) ?

Comment: @Tim is that a joke or a cultural difference?!

Comment: @javapalava that's a **really** bad joke (pointers are used in c/c++)

Comment: What do you mean "must not exceed character 2"?

Comment: 3 must not be printed more times than character 2. So if 2 has printed 6 times, then 3 can have printed 6 times or less.

Comment: Does anyone have any advice at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider creating two different classes for your threads (and possibly a common abstract superclass) instead of the `if/else` fork inside the run().

Now, take a look at the [Semaphore class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), be sure to read the description in the beginning of that page, it is really helpful to understand the concept.  Basically, there are two methods you care about: `acquire` and `release`. Each time you print your "2", you will call the `release` method. This increases the number of "permits" that the semaphore holds. Now, in the other thread, just before printing "3", you will call `acquire`, it will check if there are any permits available, and if not , it'll block and wait, otherwise, it will decrease the number, and return, so that you can print your "3". 
When you use it this way, the number of permits held by the semaphore at any given moment will reflect how many more "2"s have been printed than "3"s so far. There will never be more 3s than 2s, because `acquire` will not allow the number of permits go negative, if it happens to be 0, it will force your thread to wait until the other one prints another "2" and calls "release".

Comment: Thanks so much Dima - this is making sense. I've followed your advice and split the thread classes out, and I think I'm making greater sense of the idea of the Semaphore. The only issue is that now I seem to have created a deadlock scenario!! I should just have one acquire method in my class for Thread1 and one release method in my class for Thread2 right?